# Calling a Function defined inside another function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, scope

I am calling a function on button click like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="outer();" value="ACTION">​

function outer() { 
    alert("hi");       
}
```

It works fine and I get an alert:

Now when I do like this:

```
function outer() { 
    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }
}
```

Why don't I get an alert?

Though inner function has a scope available in outer function.

Comment: Where do you try to call `inner`?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The scoping is correct as you've noted. However, you are not calling the `inner` function anywhere.

You can do either:

```
function outer() { 

    // when you define it this way, the inner function will be accessible only from 
    // inside the outer function

    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }
    inner(); // call it
}
```

Or

```
function outer() { 
    this.inner = function() {
        alert("hi");
    }
}

<input type="button" onclick="(new outer()).inner();" value="ACTION">​
```

Comment: btw what is that piece called onclick="(new outer()).inner();", I am seeing it for the first time

Comment: @Mike: Better forget it, it's not really suited for this. He is creating a new instance of the `outer` constructor and calls a method on it

Comment: @Mike - In case you need `inner()` accessible outside `outer()`, the second way will let you. But you do not need the second way for your requirement here.

Answer (score 80):

You could make it into a module and expose your inner function by returning it in an Object.

```
function outer() { 
    function inner() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
    return {
        inner: inner
    };
}
var foo = outer();
foo.inner();
```

Comment: The first part of the marked answer is the correct answer for this particular question, but Google brought me here and this is actually what I was looking for, searching: "javascript access a function inside a function."  I'm guessing that's why this has so many up-votes even though it's wrong for the question.

Comment: can also `return { inner }`

Answer (score 9):

You are not calling the function `inner`, just defining it.

```
function outer() { 
    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }

    inner(); //Call the inner function

}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also try this.Here you are returning the function "inside" and invoking with the second set of parenthesis.

```
function outer() {
  return (function inside(){
    console.log("Inside inside function");
  });
}
outer()();
```

Or

```
function outer2() {
    let inside = function inside(){
      console.log("Inside inside");
    };
    return inside;
  }
outer2()();
```

Answer (score 6):

Again, not a direct answer to the question, but was led here by a web search.  Ended up exposing the inner function without using return, etc. by simply assigning it to a global variable.

```
var fname;

function outer() {
    function inner() {
        console.log("hi");
    }
    fname = inner;
}
```

Now just

```
fname();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also just use return:

```
   function outer() { 
    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }
return inner();

}
outer();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function parent() {
    this.child1 = function child1(string){
        console.log(string);
    }
    this.child2 = function child2(string){
        console.log(string);
    }
}

new parent().child1("hello world child1");
new parent().child2("hello world child2");
```

Output:

"hello world child1"

"hello world child2"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the "inner" function with the "outer" function, you can do this:

```
function outer() { 
     function inner() {
          alert("hi");
     }
     return { inner };
}
```

And on "onclick" event you call the function like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="outer().inner();" value="ACTION">​
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function outer() { 

    function inner() {
        alert("hi");
    }
    inner();
}
```

you should try this

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript

If using ES6
`static` functions can be used in a `class`

If using ES5
After several days of usage, below is what I came up with,
it is minimal & also has a lot of conveniences:

```
function MathFunctions() {
    let thefo = {}; // the functions object

    thefo.sum = sum = (a, b) => {
        return a + b;
    };
    thefo.avg = avg = (a, b) => {            // name is repeated 2 times - minor inconvenience
        return sum(a, b) / 2;                // calls sum, another function without using 'this'
    };

    return thefo;                            // no need to go down & export here always for each new function - major convenience
}

// Usage
console.log(MathFunctions().sum(1, 2));
console.log(MathFunctions().avg(1, 2));
// OR
const mf = MathFunctions();
console.log(mf.sum(1, 2));
console.log(mf.avg(1, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Solution**

```
const greet = (greeting) => {
    return function (name) {
        console.log(`${greeting} ${name}`);
    };
};

greet('Hi !')('JAHID');
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can write like this

```
function outer() { 
function inner() {
    alert("hi");
}
return {inner}
}
```

https://medium.com/@mikkanthrope/dot-notation-to-access-nested-functions-in-javascript-fab346c65d9a
This page provides in depth explanation

Now you can call it like this

```
outer().inner();
```