# How to access nested function in Javascript from another function?

Tags: javascript, function

In case I have

```
import axios from "axios";

function model() {
  function getAll() {
    return axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000/teams")
      .then(response => response.data);
  }
}

export default model;
```

How can I access `getAll()` method from another component ?

I tried importing `model` and then referring it to getAll - `model.getAll()`, but it complains that the method is undefined.

I tried referring to [Calling a Function defined inside another function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218472/calling-a-function-defined-inside-another-function-in-javascript)
, but could not find the solution.

Is this even the correct approach?

Comment: return `getAll` from `model()`

Comment: Maybe you can put teams in a seperate file and export it: `export default axios.get(....` and just import teams `import teams from './teams';teams.then(teams=>....`

Answer (score 4):

You can't access `getAll` from anywhere except inside `model`. Maybe you meant to create an object?

```
var model = {
    getAll: function () { ... }
}

model.getAll();
```

Comment: For some reason I thought I was meant to do it this way. In case I was doing it as I normally do, I would just export the function and then import it. Since it's not possible, I must've not figured it out correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could always instantiate the function

```
function model() {
  this.getAll = () => {
    console.log("hello world");
  };
}

const myFunc = new model();

myFunc.getAll() // console.log('hello world')
```