# use the result of a text box outside the function in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, object

I have a text box with a button

```
<div id="myset">
    <input id="dataset" class="myinput" type="text"  placeholder="Insert your sentence" >
    <button id="data" class="in_button" onclick = "myclickFnt()" ><a class="little-arrow">&#8711;</a> 
</button>
</div>
```

When the user insert the sentence i take that on the onclick function

```
 function myclickFnt() {
     document.getElementById("myinit").style.display = "block";
     var y =  document.getElementById("dataset").value;
 }
```

My problem is that i want to use the inserted sentence not in the function but ouside it. More spesific i want to put the sentence (var y) in an object that it's outside in the onclick function. Also i want to clarify that the object can't be inserted on the onclick function because it is called from another function. i don't know if this is capable to implemented

I hope my question is not ambiguous

***EDIT: I solved my problem [with this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218472/calling-a-function-defined-inside-another-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Hello, Basically you want the value to be used globally outside the function?

Comment: yes i think that it correct

Answer (score 1):

I am a little unclear on what you want to achieve, but if I understood it correctly, you can do something like this:

```
 var y;
 function myclickFnt() {
     document.getElementById("myinit").style.display = "block";
     y =  document.getElementById("dataset").value;
 }
```

After the comments, I realized you are using a document ID that's not present in the HTML. Either use a valid one or delete it. Here's a debug code snippet.

```js
var y;

function myclickFnt() {
  y = document.getElementById("dataset").value;
  callMe();
}

function callMe() {
  alert(y);
}
```

```html
<div id="myset">
  <input id="dataset" class="myinput" type="text" placeholder="Insert your sentence">
  <button id="data" class="in_button" onclick="myclickFnt()"><a class="little-arrow">&#8711;</a> 
</button>
</div>
```

Now you can use `y` for everything

Comment: i want to know what the user inserted in the text box and i want to put this on an object but my problem is that the object must not be in the onclick function because is called from other function

Comment: with the above answer the y variable is defined as "undefined" and don't get the inserted value

Comment: the id document that's not present in the HTML is used to show up a form when the button is clicked . In the end i want an object like this: var = myobj ["your sentense is"+y]  but i don't want it inside a function

Comment: Honestly, I am lost here. The code I presented does what you are asking for. If you are calling an id not present in the document, it will return an error and not continue to execute the code. You probably should post a clearly structured question with all necessary files and codes.