# How can i onclick a function inside a function in html?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, onclick

Hey how can i call a function inside a function like

```
Html
<button onclick"b()">b</button>

JS
    function a() {
      function b() {
        bot.chat("Hi")
      }
    }
```

what should we do cause I cant do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a Function defined inside another function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218472/calling-a-function-defined-inside-another-function-in-javascript)

Comment: You can't do it because you can't do it.

Comment: not really what do this. mean ?

Comment: You can not call b() because it is not in scope. The stuff inside of A is in a black box. You can not see what is in A from the outside. Only way to see what is in A is if the method A when called exposes properties that you can call.

Comment: Hey what is  return { inner }; do ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score 0):

You can't becuase `b` is not defined in the [Scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope) you are trying to call it. `b` is only accessible inside function `a` and its inner scope not outer scope.

see the example below

```js
function a() {
  function b() {
    console.log("Hi")
  }
}

try{
  b()
}catch (err){
  console.log("execption raised since 'b' is not in scope")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
function a() {
  function b() {
     bot.chat("Hi");
  }
  b();
}

<button onclick"a()">b</button>
```

**or this:**

```
function a() {
  this.b = () => {
     bot.chat("Hi");
  };
}

<button onclick"new a().b();">b</button>
```