# Callbacks: How do Functions Access other Functions?

Tags: javascript, function, callback, scope

Well, first see my code:

```
function cubosSuma(a,b,callback) {
    var res = (a*a*a)+(b*b*b);
    callback(res);
    }
function resultado(res) {
    console.log(res);
    };
cubosSuma(3,2,resultado); //line 8;
```

What I want to understand is why I can call 'resultado' in cubosSuma (line 8) if it is supposed to be that a function has its own scope. I mean, why is it possible to get to callback(res) from another function?

Comment: It isn’t  clear to me what effect you think scope should have on anything in the posted code. You can always pass functions as arguments like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `resultado` is defined before it is used on the last line of code, so that's how your program know what it is. Not that it matters for Javascript as Javascript uses hoisting which you can read more about at https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp

`callback` in the `cubosSuma` function is just a placeholder name... when you call `cubosSuma` on the last line of code, it replaces the placeholder `callback` with the function you pass to it... which is `resultado`

And using functions within other functions is a feature of Javascript and has been since forever. See this SO article for more info - [Calling a Function defined inside another function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218472/calling-a-function-defined-inside-another-function-in-javascript)